# Responsive Nav menu not opening since transfer

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, nav

I've been building a responsive wordpress theme for a client and it is all working on the build domain I used 101share.co.uk but now after uploading a copy of the site to the clients domain (wincheapguesthouse.org) the responsive/device menu no longer seems to open when clicked or tapped. The css seems fine to me and it still works on the other domain.

Is there something I'm missing? It would be great if someone could help me shed some light on this problem.

Comment: What is the 'other' domain?  Hosting service, platform, etc?

Comment: They're both hosted by the same host, the other domain is wincheapguesthouse.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using any cache plugin on [later site](http://wincheapguesthouse.org)

if yes, try to disable and test.

Comment: Yes, I disabled the w3 total cache plugin I was using. Do you know why that would affect the responsive menu?

Comment: Also do you know a way to avoid that from happening when I use the plugin?

Comment: try using w3 super cache [link] (http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/w3-total-cache-wordpress-plugin) than w3 total cache plugin